# How to create an Interface for a class that extends JDialog (or in general another class)

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, implementation

I'm developing a Java application that makes use of Swing.
I have a class that extends a JDialog, like this:

```
public class customDialog extends JDialog {
    //Custom buttons listeners etc.
}
```

Now what is the manner (best practice) to create an interface for it?
I would write:

```
public interface customDialogInterface {
    //Custom methods signatures
}
```

and then use the "implement customDialogInterface" in customDialog but in this manner when I use the customDialogInterface in my code I have no access to the JDialog methods. 
Otherwhise JDialog is a class so I can't extend it in my interface. Furthermore I can't extend customDialogInterface with the interfaces that JDialog implements because one of them is package protected.

What is the correct manner to proceed in those (I suppose commons) cases?

---

UPDATE 1:
I'll try to explain better reformulating my question.
There is a programming principle that tells "program using interfaces and not concrete classes". Basing on it, how can I create an interface for my CustomDialog? 
If I do:

```
public interface CustomDialogInterface {
    public void doA();
    public void doB();
}
```

than in the code that uses CustomDialog I have:

```
CustomDialogInterface myDialog = new CustomDialog();
myDialog.doA();    //OK
myDialog.doB();    //OK
myDialog.setVisible(true);    //ERROR
```

---

UPDATE 2: I decided to update again my question because basing on the answer it seems that it is not very clear. It has not many info because it is not yet real code, it is just a theoretical question. Also if I yet found a possible solution I write here again in another form:

1. In my application I need a JDialog with my info, fields etc.
   How can I obtain it? 
   Defining a class:

   class MyImplementation extends JDialog { 
      public doA(String txt) {
          //This is a method specific of my implementation
      }
   }
2. Now, I want to follow the rule of good programming "Program by interface, not by implementation" so I need an interface for my custom dialog

   interface InterfaceForMyDialog {
       public doA(String txt);
   }
3. Obiously the class MyImplementation has to implement the interface so I change the pseudocode above just adding and implements

   class MyImplementation extends JDialog implements InterfaceForMyDialog {
       public doA(String txt) {
          //This is a method specific of my implementation
      }
   }
4. Now finally I need to use my new dialog somewhere in the external code (let say somewhere in the main method) like this:

   ...
   InterfaceForMyDialog myDialogInterface = new MyImplementation(...);

QUESTION: 
How should you complete the code above to set some text to my custom dialog using the method "doA(String txt)" and then show the dialog itself ?
I think it is not possible using this structure and I found a solution (see below) using an abstract class. If I'm wrong or there is a better solution explain please write it here.

Comment: WHAT error? copy and paste it here. Is it a compile error?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). Based on your limited information I would suggest that your only implementing the interface and not extend the dialog, as described by Andrew

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you can only extend one class; since you are extending JDialog, you can implement 0 or more interfaces, but you cannot extend another class.

If your interface has two methods:

```
public interface customDialogInterface
{
  public void doA();
  public int  doB();
}
```

then your class can have

```
public class customDialog extends JDialog implements customDialogInterface
```

as long as `customDialog` has the methods `doA()` and `doB()`.

As a note: by convention, both class names and interface names start with capital letters. Java programmers the world over will find it easier to understand your code if you use `CustomDialog` and `CustomDialogInterface`.

Comment: EDIT: I updated the original question instead of writing a comment.

Comment: When you ask questions on SO, don't just say "ERROR" or "it doesn't work". Copy the error and paste it into your question. Say WHAT doesn't work, say if it's compile or run time (which you have done here), etc. Try to imagine that all of us here on the internet are just coming to see any part of your problem for the very first time. If you have an instance of CustomDialog, and it extends JDialog, and you call setVisible on it with a boolean, there should not be a compile error at that point.

Comment: Hi arcy, it is not a real error, it is only an example. I meant that I want to call the method setVisible(true) on the CustomDialogInterface but I can't because that method is a method of JDialog and is not defined in the interface. BTW I found a soultion, make CustomDialogInterface as abstract class instead of as an interface. Thanks in any case for having a look to my question.
Best,

Comment: As it stands, you appear to have a misunderstanding about the workings of a class that extends a class plus implementing an interface. I'd like to clear that up for you. There is no reason you cannot call setVisible() on CustomDialog if it extends JDialog, whether it implements an(other) interface or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution.
Instead of declaring CustomDialogInterface as interface I declared it as an abstract class that extends the JDialog. Then I extend this abstract class with the class that provides the implementation.
If there is a better solution let me know!

Comment: Whether this is better or not depends on things you have not told us. It is perfectly possible to extend JDialog and implement an interface as well; if you have an error, then tell us what the error is and when it shows up. Some here insist on running code, and this is why -- there is often not enough (or much of any) thought given to providing enough information.